# API Platform - No identifiers defined for resource of type

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have an Doctrine Entity Class identified by an iso_code attribute :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     graphql={
 *          "item_query",
 *          "collection_query"
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LanguageRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Language extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2, unique=true)
     */
    private $iso_code;

    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->iso_code;
    }

    public function getIsoCode(): string
    {
        return $this->iso_code;
    }
}
```

When I try to access a list through a GET requests `/api/v2/languages?pages=1`, I got `"No identifiers defined for resource of type \"App\\Entity\\Language\""` error.

When I try to access an item through a GET requests `/api/v2/languages/en`, I got `Invalid identifier value or configuration`

Configuration:
- api platform v2.5.6
- php 7.4
- symfony 4.4

Comment: Sorry it was 1.2.2 of `api-pack`

Comment: In Symfony every enetity must have an identifier/primary key, in your case you must have two variables one for the ID and must have a GeneratedValue as annotation and the other is the iso code

Comment: Every work outside API Platform, ISO_CODE is a primary_key unique.
I don't see anywhere in the doc that I must use a GeneratedValue ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Changing the name of the identifier to `$id` did the trick.

But I can't get why it's not possible to use `$iso_code`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add

```
App\Entity\Language
  properties: 
    id: 
      identifier: false
    iso_code:
      identifier: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved similar issue by setting identifier   @ApiProperty(identifier=true)   on top of the
getter function